# Botocore object issue.

Tags: python, config, botocore

I'm attempting to create custom configurations for my boto3.client. The first two parameters work (maxpoolconnect and readtimeout) but the third one retries is giving me a  *Got unexpected keyword argument 'retries'* heres the link to the documentation for reference.

http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html

`config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=50,read_timeout=1,retries={'max_attempts':0})`

Comment: Does your version match the docs? What's `botocore.__version__`? What does the traceback show; post the full error, verbatim.

Comment: Got unexpected keyword argument 'retries': TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 22, in index
    config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=50,read_timeout=1,retries={'max_attempts':0})
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/config.py", line 107, in __init__
    args, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/config.py", line 132, in _record_user_provided_options
    'Got unexpected keyword argument \'%s\'' % key)
TypeError: Got unexpected keyword argument 'retries'

Comment: [Edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45704697/edit) to insert the traceback. Please run `python -c "import botocore;print(botocore.__version__)"`, what does it output?

Comment: 1.5.80, not sure why its running on that version

Comment: Documentation from different versions is unreliable. Either find a version of the docs that match your package version, or update your package to match the docs.

Comment: python -c "import botocore;print(botocore.__version__)" resulted in 1.6.2. Reuploaded my lambda function and it still returns the same key error.

Comment: Any suggestion as to what could be off?

Comment: Edit your answer and post the traceback with the current version. If it's the *exact same* error, you probably didn't update the running package.

Comment: Appreciate the help, issue resolved, as you mentioned it wasn't in the correct package